# doubly linked list, current.next = null

Tags: java, list, pointers, null, linked-list

Doing a homework problem, the first item inserted into the linked list inserts fine, when I insert more values they appear out of order because current.next remains == null according to debugger, I can't figure out why for the life of me.

```
public void insert(String key)    
{    
 Link newLink = new Link(key);    
Link current = first;     

 Main.nodeCount++;
 while(current != null && key.compareTo(current.dData) > 0)  
 {              
 if(current.next != null)
 current = current.next;
 else
 break;
 } // end while                                                                                                                                    

 if(isEmpty())
 {
 first = newLink;
 last = newLink;
 return;
 }

 if (current == first )        
 {
 if(key.compareTo(current.dData) < 0)
 {
 newLink.next = current;
 current.previous = newLink;
 first = newLink;
 return;
 }//end if

 if(key.compareTo(current.dData) > 0)
 {
 current.next = newLink;
 first.next = newLink;
 newLink.previous = current;
 return;
 }//end if
 }
 if (current == last)
 {
 if(key.compareTo(current.dData) < 0)
 {
    current.previous.next = newLink;
    newLink.previous = current.previous;
    newLink.next = current;
    current.previous = newLink;
    last = current;
 }

 if(key.compareTo(current.dData) > 0)
 {
    newLink.previous = current;
    current.next = newLink;
    last = newLink;
    return;
 }//end if
 return; 
 }//end if

 if (current != first && current != last)
 {
 current.previous.next = newLink;
 newLink.previous = current.previous;
 newLink.next = current;
 current.previous = newLink;    
 }
```

Comment: turns out the problem was by not declaring a new last pointer after adding new links in the current == first statements, I was messing up the order in some way.  I will try to figure out a more precise answer tomorrow when I've actually slept :)

Answer (score 0):

Add 'last = newLink' in the if block as follows:

```
if(current == first) {
    ....

    if(key.compareTo(current.dData) > 0) {

        last = newLink;
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

This is required because if the control goes to that if block, then the current is the last Link. Otherwise, the current would have been another Link on the right of current, on completion of the while loop above.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isEmpty())
{
   first = newLink;
   first.next = NULL;  //need to initialize next and prev pointers 
   first.prev = NULL;

   last = first;
   return;
}

if (current == first )        
 {
  if(key.compareTo(current.dData) < 0)
  {
  newLink.next = current;
  current.previous = newLink;
  first = newLink;
  return;
  }//end if

  if(key.compareTo(current.dData) > 0)
  {
  current.next = newLink;
  // first.next = newLink;   --> redundant
  newLink.previous = current;
  newlink.next = NULL;
  last = newLink   -->
  return;
  }//end if
```